# Technisat does not provide LINUXdriver

Tags: drivers

My -Technisat sky star 2- TVcard needs LINUXdrivers wich are not provided by Technisat. 
What can i do?
I am a 74 old LINUXbeginner,until recently windowsuser und would be glad to find a solution for nonexperts like me and help to get away from windows.
Thanks Robert

Comment: Is this the same as  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iS2wyCMcX4g ?

Answer (score 0):

[LinuxTV seems to suggest it's quite a well supported card](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/TechniSat_SkyStar_2_TV_PCI_/_Sky2PC_PCI). If its modules aren't being automatically loaded you might just need to do that. To test just run:

```
sudo modprobe budget
sudo modprobe stv0299
```

Edit: On the newest revision, you need a different driver that hasn't yet made it into the Kernel. This driver is available from Technisat by searching for `skystar 2` but here's [a direct link](ftp://tsdownload%3aJP7g5hVD@ftp1.technisat.de/assets/medias/common/23/app_Linux-Driver_001.bz2). This contains instructions on how to patch v4l and recompile it. It's a bit of a pain but it can be done.